# basepath in jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets, path, radix

In my application,I use the struts2,and I create a base action to slove the path problem:

```
class BaseAction{
  private String path;
  static{
  HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest(); path=request.getScheme()+"://"+request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()+request.getContextPath();+"/";
  }
}
```

Then all other action extend this baseaction.

In my jsp page,I add the path as the base:

xx.jsp:

```
....
<head>
  <base href="<s:property value='path'/>">
  <script ... src="res/test.js" />
</head>
```

It works well in my own machine.

http://localhost:8080/app
The test.js canbe found by "http://localhost:8080/app/res/test.js"

But when other people try to visit my app,they use:

http://192.168.x.x:8080/app.

now,the browser still try to download the test.js by 
"http://localhost:8080/app/res/test.js"

Of course,it can not get it. The real path should be:
http://192.168.x.x:8080/app/res/test.js

SInce, the "path" is hard code in teh action,any idea to fix this?

Comment: Can you verify that the base href is correct in the HTML these other people see? And accessing the Servlet context or request from a static initializer seems asking for trouble.

Comment: ... as does setting an instance variable from a static initializer. How does that even compile?

Comment: In the html page which other people see,the base href is stil "http://localhost:8080/app "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a `static` initialization block I wouldn't expect you to have a request available. I'd do:

```
<base href="${request.contextPath}" />
```

Comment: @hguser - my answer still applies, I think.

Comment: Thanks ,I will have a try tomorrow.

Comment: you are right, I should not set the path in a static block,it should be got in each request.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
<base href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the local host and port in the base path instead of the remote host and port.

This is after all not a nice construct to create the base path. I'd suggest to create it as follows instead:

```
path = request.getRequestURL().toString().replace(request.getRequestURI(), request.getContextPath()) + "/";
```

Or just nicely in JSTL/EL

```
<c:set var="r" value="${pageContext.request}" />
<base href="${fn:replace(r.requestURL, r.requestURI, r.contextPath)}/" />
```

Comment: Do you mean that I can not use the static block,and I should create teh path according to  each request?

Comment: I didn't said that and I have no idea since I don't do Struts2, but you at least told that it works locally and not remotely, this behaviour is indeed confirmed by the incorrect way how you extract the base path (you used the local address instead of the remote address). Did you try my suggestion anyway?

Comment: Now,I am at home,I will try you suggestion tomorrow. :)